# Split one file into Multiple GDG dynamically

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos, dfsort, easytrieve

Input file has number of records . when there a change in header (12), i need to write those records separately into GDG

Is it possible to create GDG dynamically using SORT, Easytrive?

12 - header
13 - Detail

```
Input File:

123456777
130000001
130000002
130000003
125453453
130000004
130000002
130000900
124543543
130043353
130043352

output should be

File1.GV***:

123456777
130000001
130000002
130000003

File2.GV***:

125453453
130000004
130000002
130000900

File3.GV***:

124543543
130043353
130043352
```

Comment: What is your question?  Can you create a GDG dynamically?  Yes, if the stem is already defined, you can address the GDG using relative terms.  FILE(0) is the current generation, and File(+1) is the next generation, which will be automatically created.

Comment: To restate what your asking for.  Can I sort 1 input file and create multiple output files to a GDG in one sort step?   So, inf your example I would have File1(+1) File2(+2) and File3(+3) so +3 would be the most recent ... is that correct ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a new GDG entry when ever there is a new header record using a utility. The answer was **no** when I last used the mainframe (and probably still is), you would need to dynamically allocate new files. Also `why would you want to`, I think there will be a better solution

Comment: Input file has more than 100 headers n detail records, creating physical output file would be tedious  , hence tot of creating GDG dynamically.. is there any better solution to achieve this?